# How to pull info from a workbook which changes names weekly?

Tags: excel, vba, file

I have code that opens up the latest workbook file in a specified folder.

The macro I have setup to pull information from that workbook file won't work week to week. The macro references the workbook file which is named 2019-09-16 but next week the workbook file will be 2019-09-20.

If I could save a copy of the workbook in another folder under a generic name for example Archive that would allow me to get information from that workbook.

I attempted type the code I had for opening the latest file to help link something together with the macro but I got many errors.

```vb
Sub OpenLatestFile()

Declare the variables
Dim MyPath  As String
Dim MyFile  As String
Dim LatestFile  As String
Dim LatestDate  As Date
Dim LMD  As Date

MyPath = "\\C\s\CAF7\Stats\Team 1\Archive\"
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

If LMD > LatestDate Then
    LatestFile = MyFile
    LatestDate = LMD
    End If
MyFile = Dir

Loop
Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

Windows("Teams.xlsm").Activate
Range("F11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile]Managers Sheet'!R33C13"
Range("E12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile]Managers Sheet'!R24C13"
Range("D9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile]Managers Sheet'!R38C13"
Range("F13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='T1'!R[7]C"
Range("F14").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='T1'!R[20]C"
Range("F15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='T1'!R[33]C"
Range("F16").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='t1'!R[19]C[2]"
Range("F17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='t1'!R[18]C[8]"
Range("E18:F27").Select
End Sub
```

This is what I have tried. The workbook opens but when trying to run the macro it tries to find the workbook from the reference and can't locate.

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have?

Comment: You are mixing terms "file" and "sheet" and it's a little confusing: a "file" is a WorkBook, and a "sheet" is a tab in a workbook.  Also you will avoid your question getting closed by including your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one sheet in the file (with the currently updated information) then simply refer to the sheet by its index

```
TheLatestFile.Worksheets(1)
```

If there are multiple sheets and you can definitively know where it is in the workbook tab order you can use that known index position instead.

```
TheLatestFile.Worksheets(KnownIndex)
```

If there are multiple sheets and you cannot know its position in the tab order you can get the correct sheet from the codename if you can ensure the codename is consistent. This approach requires the codename not change from week to week (updated file to updated file) AND you will need to Trust Access to the VBA Project model.

Comment: HI I have added my code and provided more information on the problem.

Comment: I have solved this problem, once the file is opened by my code I then created a copy of the file and called it archive and placed it in a folder. I then ran a macro to pull the information I needed into my workbook